# Configure MacBook Air at Apple Premium Resellers in Singapore

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, hardware-recommendation

I am Abhimanyu, located in Singapore. I have a question for you all: Can I configure MacBook Air at one of the Apple Premium Resellers?

I want to buy 13" MacBook Air, but I need 8 GB Memory, instead of default 4 GB memory. Can I get my system configure at one of Apple Premium Resellers? Is it safe to do it? Does that void warrenty?

BTW, what is difference between Apple Premium Resellers and Apple Authorised Reseller?

If I cannot get MacBook Air configure at Apple Premium Resellers, can I get it configure at Apple Authorised Resellers?

Answer (score 1):

"Difference between Apple Premium Resellers and Apple Authorised Reseller": The premium resellers are supposed to have better service and more knowledgable staff.

Unless the Premium resellers stock the CTO (configure to order) models then you will need to order it online.

The majority of Apple Retail Stores will not carry that model but some Resellers do.  So I would check with the particular store.

As the other commenter stated you cannot physically put more ram into a MacBook Air once it is already put together.  The ram is soldered onto the Logic Board.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the MacBook air and 15" Retina MacBook Pros, the RAM memory chips are directly soldiered onto mother ('Logic') board, rather onto removable modules that slot into DDR3 connectors (for example). As such, "upgrading" the memory on these devices isn't really possible, instead, different configurations are made during manufacturing. (much like the capacity of an iPhone, it can't be changed; it can only be exchanged for a whole different device that was built with the desired capacity)

Comment: I know that memory chips are soldiered, but online store provide option to configure. Is same option available for Apple Premium/Authorized resellers too?

Comment: Your selection will be limited to the "base" configurations, as offered on the Apple website. Further customizations require a made-to-order device to be made.